# input type "file" is not working on iPad

Tags: php, html, ios, ipad

In my form I'm using a file uploader. It's working fine on MAC, But it's not working on iPad.

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" >

<input type="file" name="actFile" />

</form>

$imgName = $_FILES['actFile']['name'];
$tempFile = $_FILES['actFile']['tmp_name'];
$targetFile = 'images/' . $imgName;

$scss = move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
```

I'm confused,

Comment: Change `action="#"` to `action=""`

Comment: Yea.. I tried that. But same prob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update (On 2017)

Now if you specify the input type as `file` the OS will allow you to choose from available file sources like PhotoLibrary, iCloud etc. However if you are showing the html page inside an app using WebView, then you need to ask for corresponding permissions. For example, if you want to choose image from PhotoLibrary; then you need to specify the `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` key in your app's `info.plist` file. If you don't do that the app will crash by raising an exception.

#### Original Answer (On 2014)

<strike>There is no option to browse files in iPad.</strike>

That's why the `file input` is not working in iPad.

It'll work on mac because, mac have finder for browsing the files and it is allowed. But in iPad it is not allowed.